# Add UISearchBarController to a UITableViewController Without IB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a UITableViewController and I want to add a UISearchBarController at the top so it searches with a different table view (not the table view of the UITableViewController).

How can I initialize this via code and no IB?

```
@interface mySearchController : UITableViewController <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) UISearchDisplayController *aSearchBarController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISearchBar *aSearchBar;

@end

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {

        UISearchBar *tempSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 0)];
        self.aSearchBar = tempSearchBar;
        self.aSearchBar.delegate = self; 
        [self.aSearchBar sizeToFit];  
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.aSearchBar;  
        [self.aSearchBar release];

        UISearchDisplayController *tempSearchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:aSearchBar contentsController:self]; 
        self.searchDisplayController = tempSearchDisplayController;
        self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
        self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
        self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cursory glance at the [`UISearchDisplayController Class Reference`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008225-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1) would answer your question.

> "Typically you initialize a search display controller from a view
>   controller (usually an instance of UITableViewController) that’s
>   displaying a list. To perform configuration programmatically, set `self` for the search display controller’s view controller and search results data source and delegate."

So it should look like this:

```
searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self]; 
searchController.delegate = self;
searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
```

If you follow this pattern, then in the table view data source and delegate methods you can check the methods’ table view argument to determine which table view is sending the message:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 
    if (tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        return ...;
    }

    // If necessary (if self is the data source for other table views),
    // check whether tableView is searchController.searchResultsTableView.
    return ...;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added some code to the question.  Am I doing it right?

Comment: It all looks correct, except that I would perform the setup in `-viewDidLoad` to guarantee that the table view you're adding it to is non-nil. Also, you don't need to assign the `self.searchDisplayController` as that is handled by `initWithSearchBar:contentController:`. The controller passed into `contentController` will automatically have it's `searchDisplayController` property set.

Comment: I'm now sure what my IB should look like, I've decided to do it in IB. Essentially, I have a tableview with 4 rows, each of the 4 rows functions as a filter for the search. The 4 rows have a checkmark when clicked. Then when you search, it shows the results. I got everything working except for updating the tableview after searching.  Can you tell me if I'm on the right path?  I've uploaded a pic above of the IB file layout.

Comment: If you're filtering on a few items you could probably forgo the table view all together and use the scope buttons on the search bar. You're basically re-implementing the same behavior.

Comment: I which I could do that but I can't change the UI unfortunately.  It may be because the filter text is long and you can select multiple filters for a search.

Comment: Actually depending on what you want to happen when the user taps the search button or chooses a result, you could get away with just a view controller with the search bar. Like the search tab in the app store.

Comment: I never use UITableViewController because barely adds any functionality and is hard to customize in IB. if you want anything more